# Array of date by each week

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails

I have two dates, example :

```
date1 = "4-02-2017".to_date
date2 = "4-02-2017".to_date + 29
```

I try to get array of date by each week with this :

```
(date1..date2).select{|x| Date::DAYNAMES[x.wday] == Date::DAYNAMES[date1.wday] }
```

Rersult :

```
[Sat, 04 Feb 2017, 
 Sat, 11 Feb 2017,
 Sat, 18 Feb 2017, 
 Sat, 25 Feb 2017,
 Sat, 04 Mar 2017]
```

Is there a better way to solve the case other than the way as above?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to look up the day's name in the `DAYNAMES` array. You already have the `wday` values, so you can just compare those directly.

I.e. if

```
Date::DAYNAMES[x] == Date::DAYNAMES[y]
```

it follows that

```
x == y
```

so:

```
(date1..date2).select { |date| date.wday == date1.wday }
```

Or, simpler, you can specify a step for the range and just skip one week at a time:

```
(date1..date2).step(7).to_a
```

Now, a week is *typically* 7 days long, but there have been a few cases of nations choosing to officially [move to the other side of the international dateline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line#Samoan_Islands_and_Tokelau_.281879_and_2011.29), causing a week to not be 7 days long in their calendar. It's rare of course, but something to be aware of.